# Is it possible to simulate a `go back one character` motion which works in both LTR and RTL environment?

Tags: autohotkey, right-to-left, bidirectional, arrow-keys, bidi

When one would like to go back one character in a text field or a text editor or a web browser, an almost universal command is pressing the `left arrow key'. Obviously this only works when the direction of the text is left-to-right (LTR).

When the direction of the text is right-to-left (RTL) one should press the `right arrow key' for achieving the same purpose.

Is it possible to simulate a `go back one character` motion which works universaly in both LTR and RTL environments (possibly with autohotkey or with other solution).

Comment: Is the right-to-left in different program from the other text? Or will it be in the same window?

Comment: @ZackTarr, it could be in a same program. For example imagine you are searching a LTR or a RTL string in the search box of Google by Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Sorry I dont know of a way to approach that. But Ill see what I can try and find. Good luck. Actually follow up question, are they going to be different languages or characters between LTR and RTL? Or are they going to be the same characters between?